# Extension not accessible

Tags: vb.net, extension-methods, rectangles

I have a module called "RectangleExtension", and it already contains several extension that work now.

Now I added "FromLTWH":

```
<System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()>
Public Function FromLTWH(ByVal uLeft As Integer, ByVal uTop As Integer, ByVal uWidth As Integer, ByVal uHeight As Integer) As Rectangle
    Return Rectangle.FromLTRB(uLeft, uTop, uLeft + uWidth, uTop + uHeight)
End Function
```

However, it's not accessible when I type

```
Rectangle.From (...)
```

Only

```
Rectangle.FromLTRB
```

is.

Does anybody know why and how to fix this?

Comment: Your method creates a rectangle its not acting on one which is what extensions do.  The first parameter to an extension method would be that object/item.

Comment: @Plutonix Can you show me what I'm missing or how I should rewrite it? Or is this not an extension and therefore not possible at all?

Comment: *That* method extends int32 since the first param is an int.  If the first param was a Rect, it would show up, but you would need a Rectangle object to use it which defeats the purpose.  `FromLRTB` is not an extension but a shared/static method.  Frnkly since you have to pass 4 params to it, it is no simpler than the Rectangle ctor

Comment: Like Plutonix says it is the _**first parameter**_ of an extension method that determines _**what**_ it will extend. Your first parameter is an `Integer` so that's why it doesn't work on a `Rectangle`. Though you cannot make static extension methods anyway, so you should rather move this to a static class or something similar.

Comment: You mean just a regular function that will return a rectangle?

Comment: Yeah, or just use the already existing [**`Rectangle` constructor**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9wcdy991(v=vs.110).aspx).